# how to improve elasticsearch suggest results

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using the elasticsearch _suggest endpoint to suggest spelling corrections ("did you mean").  One example that has come up is

"gardeing with muclh"

My search request is:

```
{
  "phrase": {
    "phrase": {
      "field": "summary",
      "max_errors": 0.5,
      "analyzer": "standard",
      "highlight": {
        "pre_tag": "<em>",
        "post_tag": "</em>"
      },
      "gram_size": 1,
      "real_word_error_likelihood": 0.95,
      "direct_generator": [
        {
          "field": "summary",
          "suggest_mode": "missing",
          "min_word_len": 3,
          "min_doc_freq": 5,
          "max_edits": 1
        }
      ]
    },
    "text": "gardeing with muclh"
  },
  "term": {
    "term": {
      "field": "summary",
      "analyzer": "standard",
      "suggest_mode": "missing",
      "size": 3
    },
    "text": "gardeing with muclh"
  }
}
```

and it returns the results:

```
{
  "term": [
    {
      "text": "gardeing",
      "offset": 0,
      "length": 8,
      "options": [
        {
          "text": "gardening",
          "score": 0.875,
          "freq": 512
        },
        {
          "text": "gardenia",
          "score": 0.75,
          "freq": 71
        },
        {
          "text": "gardeninig",
          "score": 0.75,
          "freq": 1
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": "with",
      "offset": 9,
      "length": 4,
      "options": []
    },
    {
      "text": "muclh",
      "offset": 14,
      "length": 5,
      "options": [
        {
          "text": "mulch",
          "score": 0.8,
          "freq": 190
        },
        {
          "text": "much",
          "score": 0.75,
          "freq": 527
        },
        {
          "text": "muscle",
          "score": 0.6,
          "freq": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "phrase": [
    {
      "text": "gardeing with muclh",
      "offset": 0,
      "length": 19,
      "options": [
        {
          "text": "gardening with much",
          "highlighted": "<em>gardening</em> with <em>much</em>",
          "score": 0.000007876507
        },
        {
          "text": "gardening with mulch",
          "highlighted": "<em>gardening</em> with <em>mulch</em>",
          "score": 0.000005306385
        },
        {
          "text": "gardening with muclh",
          "highlighted": "<em>gardening</em> with muclh",
          "score": 5.7017786e-7
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The problem is that the correct version is "gardening with [mulch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mulch)" but the phrase match is coming back with "gardening with much".   Note that the term suggest score for "mulch" is higher than "much" for "muclh", I assume because they score a position change higher than an omission or addition.

UPDATE:  I fixed this particular problem by adding a "maxTermFrequency" of .2 - but this seems just like a hack.  I would prefer to solve it more intelligently if possible.

Is there a way to make "gardening with mulch" be the first suggestion instead of "gardening with much" without resorting to the MaxTermFrequency?